# Are all critical points of energy geodesics?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Let $\gamma$ be a smooth curve in a Riemannian manifold and consider the arclength functional $L(\gamma) = \int_a^b |\gamma'(t)|\, dt$ and the energy functional $E(\gamma) = \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b |\gamma'(t)|^2\, dt$.  A standard Cauchy-Scwharz argument gives
$$L(\gamma)^2 \leq 2(b-a) E(\gamma)$$
with equality if and only if $\gamma$ has constant speed.  As a consequence, all constant speed critical points of energy are geodesics.

I am wondering: are there any critical points of energy which do not have constant speed?  Do they have any interesting geometric properties?

Comment: As mentioned by others in their answers, critical points of the energy functional are constant speed geodesics. What is more interesting is the question whether one can find such critical points which are not minimizers. This has been carried out successfully and is one approach to find closed geodesics on closed manifold diffeomeorphic to the sphere. What is even more interesting is the fact that the length/energy relationship has an analogy in the two dimensional case which allows to find minimal surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Euler-Lagrange equations, you will see that any critical point will obey the differential equation at the end of this section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry

If you mess around with it, you should be able to show that
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left(g_{\lambda,\kappa} \frac{dx^\lambda}{dt} \frac{dx^\kappa}{dt} \right) = 0 .$$
You can get this by applying the product rule to the outer derivative, and then substituting in the formula for the Christoffel symbol.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is a bit sloppy (though interpreting all symbols in the right way, it certainly isn't), but here we go.

Since for any variation of $\gamma$ with fixed endpoints, we have  $$0=\delta E(\gamma) =  \int_a^b \langle \dot \gamma, \delta \dot \gamma \rangle = -\int_a^b \langle \ddot \gamma, \delta \gamma \rangle,$$
and since $\delta \gamma$ can be any vector field along $\gamma$ vanishing at the endpoints, it follows that $\ddot \gamma = 0$. So any critical point of the energy functional is necessarily a constant speed geodesic.

Comment: Since $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the Riemannian metric, and hence varies along the curve, you don't get $\ddot\gamma$.  Rather you get the covariant derivative of $\dot\gamma$.  It is true that you can conclude that $|\dot\gamma|$ is constant, but it is not as easy as you make it out to be.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Thank you for your comment. Of course, I am aware of this. This is why I started my post with "Maybe this is a bit sloppy ...". Everything needs to be interpreted in the right way (which means in a covariant way etc., as you rightly point out). On the other hand, if we stay in the world of submanifolds of some Euclidean space (which actually is allowed for Nash-ish reasons), we'll generally be fine with this kind of sloppiness. Finally, I find it helps my understanding to have a sloppy argument before diving into the details of formal proof.